# Email Reader in Java

Tags: java

I am writing an application in java to read the inbox of the input email address provided its credentials. So far with Javamail I can only connect to mail servers supporting IMAP and POP3.

My queries are:

1. Is any way to connect to mail servers which do not support IMAP and POP3?
2. Can we connect and read exchange emails with Javamail API?

I have found exjello for connecting to exchange mail servers but I am not able to connect to my corporate mail server.

Comment: I don't see anything about javascript here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the JavaMail FAQ, only IMAP and POP3 are supported "out of the box" but the API has been designed to support other formats as well that 3rd parties can provided plug ins for.

Here is a list of [3rd party plugins](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) for JavaMail which includes exjello that you mentioned above. Maybe one of these will give you better luck.